# How to create a proper XHR request in AJAX

Tags: javascript, xml, ajax

Here's my simple web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body onload="start()">
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's my XMLHttpRequest:

```
function start(){
  //Name the function that will perform request
  var httpRequest;  

  //cross browser instance
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari, ...
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else if (window.ActiveXObject){ //if IE 8 and older
    httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }  

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = httpResult; //what to do after response
  httpRequest.open("GET","http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker_fast?pretty", true);
  httpRequest.send();

  function httpResult(){
    if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200){
      alert(httpResult.responseText);
    } else {
      alert("problem making request");
    }
  } 
}
```

When I load the page, it runs the code and returns the "problem making request" alert 3 times. I don't see any error pop up in the JavaScript console. Anyone have a clue as to why I'm not getting a proper response from the request?

Comment: Are you using localhost or just browsing to your file system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onreadystatechange` handler is fired every time the `readyState` property changes. This means your else part will always execute until `readyState` turns 4.

Problem is you're trying to access the `responseText` property of `httpResult`, which is the `onreadystatechange` handler. Instead use `httpRequest.responseText`.

```
if (httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200){
            alert(httpResult.responseText);
}
```

This isn't a CORS-related problem, your URL allows CORS requests.

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PZkcn/)

BTW, you must use the `onerror` handler for detecting `XHR` errors.

Comment: @KhanhTO, that was a typo. Thanks.

Comment: you are right about the responseText property. now how do i prevent onreadystatechange from firing? it gives me 3 alerts then when ready state turns 4 i get the actual data i asked for.

Comment: ok i saw that you just got rid of the else statement to prevent onreadystatechange from executing it.. am i right?

Comment: @RicardoLara, yes bro.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be violating the [`same origin policy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) restriction that's built into browsers which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests.

You can only send AJAX requests to the domain from which originated the script. In your case you are attempting to send a request to `http://data.mtgox.com` and this can only work if your page is hosted on this very same domain, which I suspect isn't your case.

Of course if the server supports [`CORS`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) it would be possible to perform such a request.

Comment: request to http://data.mtgox.com returns a json object.. i have done it successfully in another example.. let me update the question with the example that worked